# How to register from type to <T>

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on an Universal App for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, using MVVM light package and its SimpleIoc.

At the moment, I have this kind of registration :

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISettings, LocalSettings>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
```

Wich is nice, but I need to register my services through a config file (an XML).
Therefore, I found myself with the following :

```
Type interfaceType = Type.GetType(service.Interface);
Type implementationType = Type.GetType(service.Implementation);
```

"service" being a variable containing 2 strings (Interface / Implementation) specifiying the type and assembly of ISettings etc.

How can I register this 2 types to the SimpleIoc container ?

I can't to do the following :

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(interfaceType, implementationType);
```

Do I have to use another container ? Is there some extensions existing ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `SimpleIoc` type doesn't provide a non-generic method for doing this, you'll have to make your own generic method at run-time:

```
// Get the Register<T1,T2>() method
MethodInfo methodInfo =
    SimpleIoc.Default.GetType().GetMethods()
             .Where(m => m.Name == "Register")
             .Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod)
             .Where(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2)
             .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 0)
             .Single();

// Create the generic type parameters to the method
Type interfaceType = Type.GetType(service.Interface);
Type implementationType = Type.GetType(service.Implementation);

// Create a version of the method that takes your types
methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType, implementationType);

// Invoke the method on the default container (no parameters)
methodInfo.Invoke(SimpleIoc.Default, null);
```

Pretty ugly and somewhat fragile if the `SimpleIoc` interface changes in the future, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Indeed, this is not the best in case of changes.
Instead of doing this, I changed for a Unity container and its service locator adapter.

I'll mark your answer as validated if people wants to keep SimpleIoc.

Thanks !

Comment: The fact that SimpleIoc does not provide non generic register methods is really a drawback, because it makes it really difficult, if not impossible, to load types dynamically, what in my opinion is a really common thing to do. It is a pitty, though, cause I really like its simplicity.